# Issue while creating Oracle ARRAY Type in java using ArrayDescriptor

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc, websphere

If I am making a direct connection with oracle, the code is working fine.
But If I am connecting to database through datasource configured in Websphere, receiving below exception:-

> java.sql.SQLException: DSRA9122E:
>   com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection@21cf8d56 does not wrap any
>   objects of type oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.

Code that is throwing this exception is below:-

```
ArrayDescriptor desc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(PROC_IN_PARAM_ALIAS, jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection()
                .unwrap(OracleConnection.class));
```

Comment: try `WebSphereNativeJdbcExtractor.doNativeCOnnection or  WSCallHelper.getNativeConnection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error says everything -

> com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection@21cf8d56 **does not wrap any objects of type oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection**.

createDescriptor() method takes two parameter

1.Stored procedure name
 2.An object of type oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection

```
ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("Proc Name", oracleConnection);
```

jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection() methods does not returns object of type oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection and while you are trying to unwrap it, it's throwing error.

You need to do the following

1.Add below mentioned entry in your configuration file.

```
<beans:property name="accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed" value="true"/>
```

2.**Convert** `java.sql.Connection` to `oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection` and use that connection object in createDescriptor() method to create your oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor object.

Answer (score 0):

In case if someone faces this similar issue, used the [WebSphereNativeJdbcExtractor](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/nativejdbc/WebSphereNativeJdbcExtractor.html) supported by Spring to get the native connection from WSJdbcConnection:-

```
       //Extract the native JDBC connection from WSJdbcConnection
        WebSphereNativeJdbcExtractor connection = new WebSphereNativeJdbcExtractor();

        //Getting the native connection
        Connection con=connection.getNativeConnection(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection());

        ArrayDescriptor desc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(PROC_IN_PARAM_ALIAS,
                con.unwrap(OracleConnection.class));
```