# WSJDBCConnection does not wrap objects of type oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, websphere, websphere-7

I saw a similar question asked:

[Issue while creating Oracle ARRAY Type in java using ArrayDescriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32399433/issue-while-creating-oracle-array-type-in-java-using-arraydescriptor/32401450#32401450)

However my issue is that other coders on the team are using the same code and apparently it is working fine for them.

```
    Connection conn = null;
    Connection oracleConn = null;
    CallableStatement stmt = null;
    try {

        conn = this.getDataSource().getConnection();
        if ( conn.isWrapperFor(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class)) {
            oracleConn = conn.unwrap(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class);
        }
```

I did not develop this code, I found it odd they're unwrapping an OracleConnection into a regular Connection class.  Bawwwt.

I've tried a whole boat load of things, but really this code is supposed to work as is.

Now the above code generates a null pointer later on when a prepared statement is called since the if statement never fires.  I never make it inside that if statement,

However when I force myself to do an unwrapping I get:

java.sql.SQLException: DSRA9122E: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection@35c735c7 does not wrap any objects of type oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

The environment is running ojdbc14 and JVM 6.0.  Setup in WebSphere

First time poster, so I apologize in advance if I am mucking something up.

**Edit**Removed two variables from code that don't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check your config.  Your DataSource must not be pointing to an Oracle DB like you think it is.  I tested your code and it will work if your DataSource is truly pointing to an Oracle DB.

The `isWrapperFor()` method is trying to tell you that your Connection does not wrap OracleConnection, and that is also consistent with what the exception message is telling you.

You can check the datasource product information like this:

```
DatabaseMetaData metadata = conn.getMetaData();
System.out.println("DB product:  " + metadata.getDatabaseProductName());
System.out.println("JDBC Driver: " + metadata.getDriverName());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer aguibert, you solidified my suspicion it was something to do with configuration.

Now when I tried the metadata suggestion to make sure I was on Oracle, I was confirmed that the config was correctly pointing to an Oracle driver.

So no dice there.

After trial and errors several other times.  I looked into a backup directory I made with a larger sized Oracle driver.  I swapped that .jar in against the smaller one, and boom...Worked.

So the .jar I had must not have been the correct one.

Comment: ah, that's a tricky one -- was the `metadata.getDriverName()` reporting the same JDBC driver name String for both jars?

Comment: Yeah it did.

And actually, WS was printing out that meta data when publishing the web application.  

I hate to let this go, since all the ojdbc.jar files came from colleagues, which I assume work for them...And I am not sure why the different .jar would matter.  But I'll just be happy the issue was resolved.  Thanks again!

Comment: I am having the same problem with postgresql. `DSRA9122E: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.v41.WSJdbc41Connection@2dcfa36f does not wrap any objects of type org.postgresql.PGConnection.`. And I've already verified that I'm correctly using the correct jar and not using multiple copies of it. The metadata information returns all the correct values. But unwrap doesn't work. I need to use PGConnection.getNotifications() function. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Prachi it would probably be best to open a separate question, but I'm guessing you need to define a shared `<classloader>` element under your `<application>` so that the application can share the same JDBC driver classloader as the datasource

Comment: Ya. That fixed it.