# I get the `DSRA9122E: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection@d3t7e556 does not wrap any objects of type oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, websphere, websphere-liberty

Am using Websphere 18 Liberty Version. When am trying to unwrap java.sql.connection to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection  I get the

> `DSRA9122E: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection@d3t7e556 does
>   not wrap any objects of type oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

In sever.xml file am using ojdbc7.jar for datasource, also in application I added same jar from the same location. Still am facing the issue. I referred all links
[WSJDBCConnection does not wrap objects of type oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097407/wsjdbcconnection-does-not-wrap-objects-of-type-oracle-jdbc-oracleconnection][1]) like this. Still am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for `Connection.unwrap` to work properly, the Liberty DataSource and the Application must both load the vendor implementation class (oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection) from the same class loader.

Here is a simple example of how to configure both the dataSource and your application to use the same class loader to load from a single library that contains the Oracle JDBC driver,

```
<library id="OracleLib">
    <fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/oracle"/>
</library>

<application location="myApp.war" >
    <classloader commonLibraryRef="OracleLib"/>
</application>

<dataSource jndiName="jdbc/oracleDataSource">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="OracleLib"/>
    <properties.oracle .../>
</dataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to unwrap to OracleConnection. You can use Connection object to establish the connection to the DB.

```
// Get a context for the JNDI look up
DataSource ds = getDataSource();
try (Connection connection = ds.getConnection()) {
  {
   executeBusinessLogicOnDatabase(connection));
   ......
  }
  connection.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am posting it because I was unable to find a solution with the above reference. Even in the liberty documentation it's mentioned that for ear, war you should add

```
<application location="myApp.war" >
    <classloader commonLibraryRef="OracleLib"/>
</application>
```

In my server.xml, this tag was different

```
<EnterpriseApplication id="myApp" location="myApp.war" name="myApp" >
    <classloader commonLibraryRef="OracleLib"/>
</EnterpriseApplication >
```

Posting it just for the reference, if anyone misses the above point like I did.